# Running ros-based code on Nao Robot

Tags: ros, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know how to automatically make the robot to execute ros in its system?
I have managed to install ros into my Nao Robot but I have no idea how to execute " move head code ". I need to setup the environment whenever want to run ros environment.Do I have to set up the environment all the time? any way to automate?

Running on Nao's AMD Geode platform and CTC Naoqi 1.12.5.3 , Fuerte

Looking forward any idea.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71113/running-ros-based-code-on-nao-robot/) by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, if you have managed to cross-compile ROS for the NAO, the next part is going to be easy :) Download `nao_robot` from [here](https://github.com/ahornung/nao_robot) and install it in your robot, you will also need [this package](https://github.com/ahornung/humanoid_msgs). For more detailed instructions check [the ROS wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao_robot?distro=fuerte) out.

Once that's installed you can control the head by publishing **nao_msgs/JointAnglesWithSpeed** messages to the **joint_angles** topic. But there are many, many more things you can do; I'd recommend you read the documentation carefully.

Here's a quick example that you can run from the terminal (of course you can also use proper ROS messages)

```
$> rosrun nao_driver nao_controller.py
$> rostopic pub /joint_angles nao_msgs/JointAnglesWithSpeed -- '[ 1, now, Head]' '[HeadYaw,HeadPitch]' '[1,-1]'  1.0  0
```

The second command was taken from this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/69232/).

Ask if you need more help!

---

Originally posted by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) with karma: 1114 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-08-10**:
I will do that. Thanks a lot